# How could this edit adding only a question mark to the title happen?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Recently I came upon this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24541929) which did nothing more than add a question mark to the title. How could that edit happen since as far as I know a suggested edit has to change at least six characters?

Comment: Perhaps title edits don't have the six character requirement?

Comment: @TylerH I thought about that but couldn't find it mentioned anywhere.